# Replace number to a word and display

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to replace original value to another word and display it from SQL?

For example,

```
SELECT name, status FROM uploads
```

This displays:

```
 name01 2
 name02 2
 name03 1
```

I want to display:

```
 name01 pending
 name02 pending
 name03 completed
```

Any query for this?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways.`CASE` statement:

```
SELECT name, 
       case
         when status = 1 then 'completed'
         when status = 2 then 'pending'
       end as status
FROM uploads
```

or create a table `Status(idstatus,name)` with this  values and use `join`

```
SELECT u.name, s.name
FROM uploads U
join Status S on S.idStatus = U.Status
```

I recommend you second solution.
1st code is  direct solution - I know is suits you. 2nd is better for the future. When in `uploads` table appear  `3` value you won't need to change the query.

Comment: status type is int, does it affect? I am using case

Comment: @Elyor 1st code is  direct solution - I know is suits you. 2nd is better for the future. When in `uploads` table appear  `3` value you won't need to change the query.

Comment: I am ending like **... end as status**

Comment: @Elyor True :) Corrected

Answer (score 1):

Use `Case when then`

```
SELECT name, 
case when status=2 then 'pending'
when status=1 then 'completed' end case as NewStat
FROM uploads
```